# Toolstripbutton not validating textbox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a textbox, a standard button and a toolstrip containing a couple of buttons.
In the validating event of the textbox I coded to check whether it is blank.
If yes then it shows a message 'Enter Value'. When the standard button is clicked while
the textbox is empty, it's validating properly and showing the message but when the
toolstripbutton is clicked it's not validating the textbox and no message is shown. It seems that I've got to write the validation code explicitly in the
`toolstripbutton_click` event which is too troublesome when there are multiple textboxes and toolstripbuttons on a single form.

What I want to know is whether the `textbox_validating` can be fired when the toolstripbutton is clicked? Handling toolstrips is really a headache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the following in toolstripbutton click event:

```
Me.Validate()
```

Comment: As much as this might answer the question, It provides no explanation why a perfectly common, standard pattern must be deviated from in this case. Hans' answer is much better.

Answer (score 4):

The ToolStripItem classes are special, they don't derive from Control.  One side-effect of that is that they don't take the focus away from the active control.  And that prevents the Validating event from firing.

Several things you can do.  You could call the textbox' parent's ValidateChildren() method.  Or you could move the focus yourself:

```
    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        btnSave.Focus();
        if (btnSave.Focused) btnSave.PerformClick();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the textbox_validating procedure from the procedure that handles the toolstripbutton click event, but you may have to add some logic to see if it passed validation before proceeding with the rest of the toolstripbutton_click event.  Since you said you have a lot of textboxes to validate, you might want to consider making a Validate() function that returns true or false and checks all of the textboxes.  Then all you have to do is check if Validate() = true and call the same function from all of your toolstrip buttons instead of copying the same code over and over again.